# How to give the path for template directory

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

My templates are not recognized and I'm getting the following error.

```
os.path.dirname(__file__)+'\\template' NameError: name 'os' is not defined
```

The code which I have used in settings is:

```
os.path.dirname(__file__)+'\\template'
```

what should I do now.

Comment: Also share the code snippet. You can put an absolute path hard coded too. Though not a good practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

os module is missing You have used it without importing

Add this in your settings.py

```
import os
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'templates'),)
```

and place all your templates under templates folder in your project

and you can use absolute paths like linux(/home/your_project/../templates) in windows ("C:/your_project/../templates")
but it is not good practice

Answer (score 2):

Import the module os

```
import os
```

Answer (score 2):

You could see the relevant knowledge in  [Definitive Guide to Django](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004VJ46OM) Page 99:

```
import os.path

TEMPLATE_DIRS =(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'templates').replace('\\','/'),)
```

Where explains how it works

> This example uses the “magic” Python variable **file**, which is automatically set
>   to the file name of the Python module in which the code lives. It gets the name of the
>   directory that contains settings.py (os.path.dirname), joins that with templates in a
>   cross-platform way (os.path.join), then ensures that everything uses forward slashes
>   instead of backslashes (in the case of Windows).

Answer (score 0):

2022 answer.
Keep templates folder in the same directory as the manage.py file

```
#settings.py

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
TEMPLATES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'templates')

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATES_DIR],
         ...
```