# app name appearing twice in url | Django

Tags: django

On my home page I have a link to a registration page.

In my browser, the home page is at `127.0.0.1:8000/app_name/`

When I click the link to register, it takes me to `127.0.0.1:8000/app_name/app_name/register/`, which gives a 404 error.

But it should take me to `127.0.0.1:8000/app_name/register/`, which displays the proper html.

In my views.py, for the Registration page I have:

`return render(request, 'app_name/register.html', {'form': form})`

In my app urls.py, for the Registration page I have:

`url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),`

Why am I getting the duplicate app_name in my url?

Update:

Here is my Project urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^app_name/', include('app_name.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Here is my app_name urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from app_name import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^register/$', views.register, name='register'),
)
```

Comment: please post your html code link for registration page and your `TEMPLATE_DIRS` in `settings.py`

Comment: My TEMPLATE_DIRS is empty (every thing is commented out). Might this be the problem? What should I have here?

Comment: how are you building the link for the register link?

Comment: <a href="app_name/register/">Sign Up</a>

Comment: u need to add path to the templates in settings.py then only it serves html pages

Comment: so where should the templates folder go? In my main project directory or inside my app directory? I currently have it in my app directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add templates dir inside of your project dir and add this path in settings.py(you can add absolute and relate path) add your html pages in this templates folder

[read my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927643/how-to-give-the-path-for-template-directory/13929894#13929894) to add path in settings.py

and in your html for link to registration page

```
<a href="/app_name/register/">Sign Up</a>
```

your view

```
return render(request, 'register.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Oops, thought it was working but still not.  So the URL is correct now, but I get a TemplateDoesNotExist error on register.html when I click the link.

Comment: Ok, just fixed it. I needed 'app_name/register.html' in the view.

Comment: No, im saying my view should be: return render(request, 'app_name/register.html', {'form': form})  rather than just 'register.html'

Comment: i didn't understand your folder structure how u placed. so .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you declaring the url in your app urls.py or the projects? (I'm wondering how many patterns declarations it's going through)

Comment: im declaring it in my app urls.py

Comment: can you share the code for the urls.py in your app as well as the one in the base project? I'm suspect the problem is lurking in one of them somewhere.